# How to run where exists with distinct faster

Tags: mysql

I have a query with WHERE EXISTS and DISTINCT. I just want to find distinct emails with same order_id

How can I make this faster

```
select  DISTINCT(user_email)
from (
         SELECT *
         FROM orders mto
         WHERE EXISTS
                   (
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM orders mti
                       WHERE mti.order_id = mto.order_id
                       LIMIT 1, 1
                   )
     ) as z
         INNER JOIN marketplaces as u ON z.ump_id = u.id
```

Comment: What is the use of `LIMIT 1, 1`?

Comment: You can try to use `hash` type index for `user_email` column

Comment: Show me your table and output that you need

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You are doing excess/needless work - the EXISTS will always return TRUE in your situation.

If you want a list of all (unique) emails which have at least 1 order, then

```sql
SELECT
  user_email
FROM
  marketplaces
LEFT JOIN
  orders ON ump_id = marketplaces.id
WHERE orders.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_email
```

If you want to get a list with all (unique) emails for a given order ID, then

```sql
SELECT
  user_email
FROM
  orders
LEFT JOIN
  orders ON ump_id = marketplaces.id
WHERE orders.id = 17
GROUP BY user_email
```